# Float elements fill top white space

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my div containers to fill all the remaining space as they flow along the page. Is there a way to get fourth box to fill that top remaining space?

Here is the example:

```css
.col {
  float: left;
}
.col > div {
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: grey;
}
.one.col {
  width: 8.33%;
}
.two.col {
  width: 16.66%;
}
.three.col {
  width: 25%;
}
.four.col {
  width: 33.33%;
}
.five.col {
  width: 41.66%;
}
.six.col {
  width: 50%;
}
.seven.col {
  width: 58.33%;
}
.eight.col {
  width: 66.66%;
}
.nine.col {
  width: 75%;
}
.ten.col {
  width: 83.33%;
}
.eleven.col {
  width: 91.66%;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:960px;margin:0 auto;">
  <div class="col six">
    <div style="height:500px;">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col three">
    <div style="height:200px;">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col three">
    <div style="height:300px;">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col three">
    <div style="height:300px;">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to throw in some JS logic which would dynamically calculate the correct position if you plan to have dynamic content there.

If you know the heights of the divs, you can just use negative top margin to move them up.

```css
  .col {
  float:left;
  }

  .col > div {
    margin:10px;
    background-color:grey;
  }

  .one.col{width:8.33%;}
  .two.col{width:16.66%;}
  .three.col{width:25%;}
  .four.col{width:33.33%;}
  .five.col{width:41.66%;}
  .six.col{width:50%;}
  .seven.col{width:58.33%;}
  .eight.col{width:66.66%;}
  .nine.col{width:75%;}
  .ten.col{width:83.33%;}
  .eleven.col{width:91.66%;}
```

```html
      <div style="width:960px;margin:0 auto;">
  <div class="col six">
    <div style="height:500px;">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col three">
    <div style="height:200px;">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col three">
    <div style="height:300px;">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col three">
    <div style="height:300px; margin-top:-100px;">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I will not know the height of the div

Comment: You'll have to calculate it then using JS. It's not a trivial thing to do if you want to cover all possible cases, so I'd suggest looking for a library if you want to get things running quickly. It's a neat exercise to implement it, though.

Comment: Another possibility is to span your content along columns if order is not important. However, if you don't have any idea about the height of these boxes, this could also produce uneven results, so it doesn't fix the problem too much.